# How to get root permission inside qt program?

Tags: 14.04, permissions, sudo, qt

I run my QT app without sudo permission but during running phase of the app I need to install the .deb so I am running the command **dpkg -i mydeb.deb** with **qprocess** in QT or some other commands which needed to sudo permisssion.

I do not need the user interaction to enter the password for the same. So how can I do the same in QT app in ubuntu 14.04 ? Thanks

Comment: If you start a software as a normal user, and then said software wants to do things to the system as `root`, all that without the user being asked for proper credentials... I'd call that a virus of sorts...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But in the below thread I got the solution. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PolicyKit and the [pkexec](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/pkexec.1.html) command to start the [QProcess](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QProcess.html) with root permissions:

```
QString dpkg_command = "pkexec dpkg -i mydeb.deb";
```

Comment: thanks. My issue is fixed now. But is there any thing in QT or in ubuntu so that I do not need to enter the password manually and app get this password from the code and automatically send the fetched password to the needed process ?

Comment: One more thing I forgot to add in my above comment that I do not need the user interaction to enter the password for the same. Sorry for that.